# RewriteCond is not working

Tags: apache2, .htaccess

In my .htaccess file

```
RewriteRule .* /test/index.php [L]
```

This code working fine on apache2 on ubuntu server.

But when I add this line

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} foo
```

It's not working. It working fine on WAMP on windows

```
Linux ip-172-31-21-17 3.13.0-48-generic #80-Ubuntu SMP Thu Mar 12 11:16:15 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Server version: `Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu)`

Comment: You said "It's not working". Can you add more info here? What request URL are you using? What response do you get? What response did you expect instead?

Comment: It was not redirecting if add `RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} foo` this to code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured solution after 6 hours. Someone please help me why it's like that

I enabled a2enmod with command `sudo a2enmod rewrite` after 6 hours of research I again tried to enable rewrite. This time fortunately I missed `sudo` and it started working.

Really confusing :(